# Pass string from .JSP form to .Java class and execute main argument

Tags: java, jsp

**Here is my index.jsp**

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"          
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

    <jsp:useBean id="ContentLoader" class="com.content.ContentLoader" scope="session"/>
    <jsp:setProperty name="ContentLoader" property="*"/> 

    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
    <title>Content Loader</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Content API: Loader</h1>

    <a>Select a CSV file from your computer.<br>

     Enter the API key and secret for your account<br>
     Click submit when you are ready to load the products!! <br>
    </a>
     <br>

    <form action="index.jsp" method="GET">
API Key: <input type="text" name="api_key">
<br>
API Secret: <input type="text" name="api_secret" />
<br>
Choose CSV File: <input type="file" name="csv_file" />
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit To Content API" />
</form>
<br>

This is feedback from the program<br>
**strong text**
You entered<BR>
Name: <%= ContentLoader.getApi_key() %><BR>
Email: <%= ContentLoader.getApi_secret() %><BR>
Age: <%= ContentLoader.getCsv_file() %><BR>

</body>
</html>
```

When I hit the submit button, I want to pass the 3 strings to the Java application.
(key, secret, and the contents of my csv)

Right now I get "The requested resource is not available" error (HTTP Status 404)

**Here is my ContentLoader.java**

```
package com.content;

public class ContentLoader {

    private String api_key = "testKey2";
    private String api_secret= "testSecret";
    private String csv_file = "testFileString";

    public ContentLoader() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    public void setApi_key(String api_key) {
        this.api_key = api_key;
    }



    public void setApi_secret(String api_secret) {
        this.api_secret = api_secret;
    }


    public void setCsv_file(String csv_file) {
        this.csv_file = csv_file;
    }


    public String getApi_key() {
        return api_key;
    }
    public String getApi_secret() {
        return api_secret;
    }
    public String getCsv_file() {
        return csv_file;
    }


}
```

The ContentLoader.java above is supposed to send and receive strings from the JSP form. When the submit button is hit, I need the 3 strings to pass to Application.java, and the main argument needs to be executed. Right now this is not happening, and I don't understand why. Thanks!!!!

**This is my Application.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;


public class Application implements ServletContextListener{

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Tomcat just started");

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Tomcat just stopped");

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("hi!! Your program is executing");

        /**

        //Null Credentials
                String apiKey = "000";
                String apiSecret = "000";



    }

}
```

Comment: You should really review how Java works, how a Servlet container works, how the HTTP request/response cycle works, and finally how JSP scriptlets work.

Comment: why have you set action as the same for your form. Any specific reason? why dont tou forward it so that a servlet could handle this?

Comment: "Tomcat just started"? You are very confused. Tomcat starts long before you app running on it does anything.

Comment: Hey all, I appreciate your help on this. Although you have interesting feedback, if you can help me solve my problem that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Web applications doesn't work like that, and Servlet don't need a main method to work, actually it doesn't know how to use it, instead of that you can use http request from your java application (main methode) to call a jsp file that returns 3 paramteres (in xml format or json) and you can pick those parametres and use them in your application as you want.